# can not pass "Date" value to php from angular js

Tags: php, angularjs, html

i am trying to pass value from my php form to my php file.
My html code following

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="EndDateSearch">Date range end date</label><br/>
            <div class="sandbox-container" id="req_end_date">
                <div class="input-group date form_datetime">
                    <input name="EndDateSearch" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select date" ng-model="EndDateSearch">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-btn form-group col-md-2">
        <button ng-click="searchWr(EndDateSearch)" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><b>SEARCH</b>
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
<form>
```

my angularJs code if following

```
$scope.searchWr = function() {
    $http.post("search_data.php", 'EndDateSearch': $scope.EndDateSearch
    })
  .success(function(myData) {
    $scope.myRequestAlldata = myData;
  });
};
```

my search_data.php contain following code:

```
if(isset($data->EndDateSearch)){
    echo $EndDateSearch=$data->EndDateSearch;
}
```

problem is if i pass date from the text box it not passing any value to search_data.php, other than date its work fine. any problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the data in the wrong way, the 2nd parameter of $http.post is an object, try to rewrite your function like this:

```
$scope.searchWr = function() {
  $http.post('search_data.php', {
      'EndDateSearch': $scope.EndDateSearch
    })
    .success(function(myData) {
      $scope.myRequestAlldata = myData;
    });
};
```

Note that the 2nd parameter is now an object.

Comment: You mean no ```EndDateSearch``` is sent to the server? Have you inspected the network? I don't see any datepicker in you code, just an input for the date, maybe there's something missing there?

Comment: Yes I can't send value to server. Yes I used date picker, even if I use HTML 5 date that also work.both HTML 5 & date picker same format but when I enable date picker value not getting my js

Comment: Pls make sure that you get the value out of datepicker; check that  $scope.EndDateSearch has some value. And please share the code with your datepicker

Comment: $scope.EndDateSearch not getting value

Comment: Problem is when i choose something from date picker  then $scope.EndDateSearch not getting any value but if i choose date from date picker then i give space or change date by typing then its $scope.EndDateSearch getting value

Comment: Share some code which includes the date picker if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.searchWr = function() {
  $http.post("search_data.php", $("form").serialize())
  .success(function(myData) {
    $scope.myRequestAlldata = myData;
  });
};
```